# Tile blocks rendering invisible in pygame platformer

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a platform game in pygame and trying to make levels easier to create by using a multi-dimensional list.

The problem is that when I go to run the game, all my blocks are there ( because I don't fall through unless I move to either side) however, the blocks are not rendering the green fill. I have no idea how to fix it and would very much appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame as pg
vec = pg.math.Vector2


pg.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 50, 0)

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 300

PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.5
JUMP = 8
JUMP_COUNTER = 2


screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("John's cool game")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 3, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed = -5
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed = 5

        self.pos.x += self.speed

    # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    # Scrolling effect
        if self.rect.left < 150:
            self.pos.x -= self.speed
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.x -= self.speed
            for powerup in powerups:
                powerup.rect.x -= self.speed

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH-150:
            self.pos.x -= self.speed
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.x -= self.speed
                if block.rect.right < 0:
                    block.kill()
            for powerup in powerups:
                powerup.rect.x -= self.speed

        if self.rect.top <= HEIGHT/4:
            self.pos.y += abs(self.vel.y)
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.y += abs(self.vel.y)

    def jump(self):
        self.vel.y -= JUMP

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.centery)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

class Block(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Powerup(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((15, 15))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.speedx = 7

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.kill()


all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
blocks = pg.sprite.Group()
powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
powerup = Powerup(WIDTH/2, (HEIGHT-HEIGHT/6)-50)

powerups.add(powerup)
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(blocks)
all_sprites.add(powerups)

jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER
doubleJump = False

BLOCK_LIST = []

level_1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]]


for y in range(0, len(level_1)):
    for x in range(0, len(level_1[y])):
        if level_1[y][x] == 1:
            BLOCK_LIST.append(Block(x*30, y*30))

for block in BLOCK_LIST:
    blocks.add(block)

# Game loop / events
gameOver = False
while not gameOver:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            gameOver = True

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE and jumpCounter > 0:
                player.jump()
                jumpCounter -= 1
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                player.shoot()

    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(CYAN)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pg.display.update()

    # Getting the powerup
    gotPowerup = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, powerups, True)
    if gotPowerup:
        print("Got powerup")
        doubleJump = True

    # Stop the player from falling through platform
    if player.vel.y > 0:
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, blocks, False)
        if hits:
            player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            player.vel.y = 0

            if doubleJump:
                jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER
            else:
                jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER-1

pg.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add group `blocks` to `all_sprites` after you add blocks to this group

```
for block in BLOCK_LIST:
    blocks.add(block)

all_sprites.add(blocks)
```

---

```
import pygame as pg


vec = pg.math.Vector2

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 50, 0)

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 300

PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.5
JUMP = 8
JUMP_COUNTER = 2

# --- classes ---

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 3, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed = -5
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed = 5

        self.pos.x += self.speed

    # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    # Scrolling effect
        if self.rect.left < 150:
            self.pos.x -= self.speed
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.x -= self.speed
            for powerup in powerups:
                powerup.rect.x -= self.speed

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH-150:
            self.pos.x -= self.speed
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.x -= self.speed
                if block.rect.right < 0:
                    block.kill()
            for powerup in powerups:
                powerup.rect.x -= self.speed

        if self.rect.top <= HEIGHT/4:
            self.pos.y += abs(self.vel.y)
            for block in blocks:
                block.rect.y += abs(self.vel.y)

    def jump(self):
        self.vel.y -= JUMP

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.centery)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)


class Block(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


class Powerup(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((15, 15))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.speedx = 7

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.kill()

# --- main ---

level_1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]]

# - init -

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("John's cool game")

# - objects -

all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
blocks = pg.sprite.Group()
powerups = pg.sprite.Group()
bullets = pg.sprite.Group()

player = Player()

powerup = Powerup(WIDTH/2, (HEIGHT-HEIGHT/6)-50)

powerups.add(powerup)
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(blocks)
all_sprites.add(powerups)

jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER
doubleJump = False

for y in range(0, len(level_1)):
    for x in range(0, len(level_1[y])):
        if level_1[y][x] == 1:
            block = Block(x*30, y*30)
            blocks.add(block)

all_sprites.add(blocks)

# - Game loop / events -

clock = pg.time.Clock()
gameOver = False

while not gameOver:

    clock.tick(60)

    # - events -

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            gameOver = True

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE and jumpCounter > 0:
                player.jump()
                jumpCounter -= 1
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                player.shoot()

    # - updates -

    all_sprites.update()

    # Getting the powerup
    gotPowerup = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, powerups, True)
    if gotPowerup:
        print("Got powerup")
        doubleJump = True

    # Stop the player from falling through platform
    if player.vel.y > 0:
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, blocks, False)
        if hits:
            player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            player.vel.y = 0

            if doubleJump:
                jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER
            else:
                jumpCounter = JUMP_COUNTER-1

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(CYAN)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pg.display.update()

# - end -

pg.quit()
#quit()
```